# Python Regex ~ Simple issue

Tags: python, regex, string

This is my code right now,

```
import re
matches = re.search(r'^%s\s*\((.*?)\)'%"Hello", "Hello(Hi())")
print matches.group(1)
```

It gets everything inside the brackets after it see's Hello.
So for example,

```
Hello(hi) produces hi
```

I'm having one problem,

```
Hello(Hi())   produces Hi( and not Hi()
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this issue by changing the regex?

Comment: It's not possible in general to match arbitrarily nested parentheses with regular epxressions, because nested parentheses don't form a regular language. Can you give a guarantee on an upper limit for nesting?

Comment: If you can guarantee that the final parentheses is somehow unique -- e.g., at the end of a line, followed by a space (and enclosed parentheses are not), etc. -- then you can anchor the end of your regular expression.

Comment: Why are you using search with a start of line anchor? This is equivalent to using match, except slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you care about is what's in the outermost parentheses, then use the `$` anchor:

```
>>> re.match("Hello\((.*)\)$", "Hello(Hi())").group(1)
'Hi()'
>>> re.match("Hello\((.*)\)$", "Hello(Hi(Bye()))").group(1)
'Hi(Bye())'
```

If you want to match nested parentheses, that's not possible with REs because your language will be [context-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) but not [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language); instead, you can iteratively apply regexes to the result of regex matches.

Comment: +1 I like the idea of matching something after the outermost parenthesis, if possible. However the comments about `*?` don't apply to your specific example. `*` would also work because `.` by default doesn't match a new line. Though it would be required if you were matching until a space, for example.

Comment: I agree with Mark. `*?` has nothing to do with why your regex works. `$` is the main idea in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If there can be arbitrary levels of nesting then regular expressions are inappropriate.

If you can be sure that there will be never more than two levels of nesting it can be solved, but it's not pleasant:

```
re.match(r'^%s\s*\(((?:[^()]*|\([^)]*\))*)\)' % re.escape("Hello"), text)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/3NHMa)

Comment: ... now you have two problems.